# How to isolate a variable in a floor function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I hope someone may be able to help me solve the following equation for $y$?

$$x=\frac b{50}\left\lfloor{50ay\over b}\right\rfloor$$

I'm trying to isolate $y$ so I can program an Excel file to solve the problem when $a$, $b$, and $x$ are known values.  Is there a way to express the formula in a way that can be relied upon with utilizing the "goal seeker" feature on each dataset. I have nearly $3000$ of these.

Comment: Do you allow $a,b,x,y$ to be non-integers? Are they all positive numbers?

Comment: Is it $$\frac{1}{50 b \operatorname{floor}(50ay/b)}$$ or $$\frac{1}{50} b \operatorname{floor}(50ay/b)$$ or what else? Please, write your formula unambiguously (use brakets).

Comment: x and y may be negative.  a and b will always be positive and they may be non-integers except for b.

Comment: It's the second example in the comment:  (1/50)*b*floor(50ay/b)

Comment: I disagree with @Crostul as your notation was perfectly unambiguous, however I have edited your question to introduce $\LaTeX$ formatting which is used on this site via [MathJax](http://mathjax.org). Please [follow this link to a basic introductory tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and familiarize yourself with $\LaTeX$ to provide better quality questions next time. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation
$$x=\frac{1}{50} b \operatorname{floor}(50ay/b)$$
is equivalent to
$$\frac{50x}{b} = \operatorname{floor}\left( \frac{50ay}{b} \right)$$
so, if $\frac{50x}{b}$ is not an integer, we have to stop, since the equation is impossible (no value of $y$ will satisfy that equation).

In the case that this is an integer, we can go on: the last equation is equivalent to
$$\frac{50x}{b} \le \frac{50ay}{b} < \frac{50x}{b} +1$$
since $\frac{50a}{b} > 0$, we can divide everything by $\frac{50a}{b}$ getting $$\frac{x}{a} \le y < \frac{x}{a} + \frac{b}{50a}$$
So every number in the interval $\left[ \frac{x}{a} , \frac{x}{a}+ \frac{b}{50a} \right)$ may be a correct value for $y$.

Comment: Where "it is impossible to solve for $y$" should be read as "there is no solutions since $\lfloor\cdot\rfloor$ always returns an integer".

Comment: The solution is not unique! I hope that this does not give you some troubles. Moreover, notice that in the case when $50x/b$ is not an integer, the equation is impossible.

Comment: My point is, "impossible to solve" is ill-defined, while "no solutions exist" or equivalently "the solution set is empty" has meaning. Additionally, I do not quite follow where did $50a/b>0$ come from.

Comment: @dbanet Thanks. I tried not to use a strictly formal language, since it seems to me that the OP is not a mathematician.

Comment: Oh, that assumption is from the comments, pardon me. Dear @apeters, please [employ the edit function](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/1683515/edit) to edit additional details about the question into your original post (OP).

Comment: Anyway, a valid answer, upvoted.

Comment: This was very helpful.  Thank you for taking the time to help out.  I'm a novice, and now understand there is no single answer for y in this equation.  I was able to use the advice and select a number in the range which will satisfy my immediate need.